# MySQL - HDD size

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve HDD size in MySQL using query?
I found only how many disc space consume database/table but how it will be useful when I don't know total HDD space?

Something similar to `xp_fixeddrives` in MSSQL

Comment: I would like to get free disk space in MySQL. I would like to have something like xp_fixeddrives which I am using in MSSQL.

Comment: You can't ask MySQL to provide you with system information such as available disk space. You can ask it to tell you how much it's using, not what the total is.

Comment: Can I use something like xp_cmdshell instead?

Comment: There is a UDF available (User Defined Function) called sys_exec (google fu > mysql sys_exec UDF). You can try to install it and then query your OS for the information. There's no out of the box solution for this in MySQL, nor is it needed really.

Comment: I don't have access to OS where MySQL database resides. Can I at least run .exe in MySQL?

Comment: What access do you have to the system of your MySQL server?

Comment: No, you can't run an executable in MySQL. If you don't have privileges to reconfigure the server, then you can't get that information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no query you can issue to MySQL to ask it about the size of the underlying hard drive.  Through configuration directives and (in some cases) symlinks, the files associated with a single MySQL instance can span multiple drives/multiple filesystems, so there's not really necessarily a single correct answer for any given installation.

Collecting this information requires access to the operating system of the host where MySQL is running.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL on a UNIX-like system, you can execute stuff on the command line from within the MySQL console:

```
\! df /dev/sda3
```

or whatever the name of your drive is.

Comment: I am not sure but I believe it is Windows. How can I test this command in SQLyog query?